# How can I use app.config for db connection string with FSharp.Data.TypeProviders?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am successfully using `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` to access my database. I am also using `FSharp.Configuration` to read values from my app.config.

Hard-coding my connection string in the F# is problematic as I deploy to  numerous staging environments. So, I would like to combine the two approaches, such that my database connection string is obtained from the app.config. Unfortunately, my initial attempts are failing.

A summarized snippet is below:

'

```
open System

open FSharp.Configuration             
open FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type Settings = AppSettings<"app.config">

// in app.config <add name="Target"  connectionString="blahblah"/>
let ConnectionString = Settings.ConnectionStrings.Target

type Sql = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionString>

// ...
use db = Sql.GetDataContext()

// query db, etc.
```

'

I understand why the type provider fails, but I would like to ask whether anybody has a suggestion for allowing me to dynamically provide a connection string?

**For clarification: I specifically want to use FSharp.Data.TypeProviders, because of the features the type provider offers me. I don't want C# solutions.**

Answer (score 0):

In a production context, you may run into issues with the normal SQL data provider, because the compiling machine needs a live connection to your DB machine. Try [the Dbml type provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362326.aspx), that works around that problem, but also allows you provide a connection string programmatically.

- You first run `sqlmetal` to extract the data base schema info into a meta language file: Run `sqlmetal /server:yourDB\SQLInstance /database:MyDB /sproc /dbml:schema.dbml` from a VS command prompt.
- You point the compiler to that schema information file - no need anymore to query the DB at compile time: `let dbml = DbmlFile<"schema.dbml">`
- You can then provide the actual connection string at runtime: `let db = dbml.MyDB(whateverConnectionString)`

A great step-by-step guide is also available on [the MSDN page about setting up Dbml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361039.aspx)

Comment: It is not true that the connection string is fixed after compilation.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Corrected. Seems I have too much of a "no mutation" mindset already ;-)